# How to integrate sveltekit app into existing .phtml file

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I can't understand how to integrate svelte kit app into existing website.

so with svelte it was straightforward. Inside my .phtml file I did:

```
some php code before
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='https://domain/build/bundle.css'/>
        <script defer src='https://diomain/build/bundle.js'></script>
        

        <div id="svelte_app"></div>

        <script>
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
                new ConfigComponent({
                    target: document.getElementById("svelte_app"),
                });
            });
        </script>
some php code after
```

now I need somethings similar but with sveltekit. Without a route for this one file that will include all required components. But I can't figure this out. Maybe someone can point me to required docs / or the direction in general?

Answer (score 1):

SvelteKit is a "full-stack" application framework (with routing, backend-endpoints, etc...), and not meant to be integrated into an existing website AFAIK.

I can't find any resources for this online, but I also remember Rich Harris saying they used Kit at the New York Times, so there must be a way I guess...

Personally, I'd stick to regular Svelte (with [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/) or [Rollup](https://github.com/sveltejs/template)) for this type of thing.